Connect to modem to configure via Android phone
Trying to login to my modem to connect a new WiFi device after replacing modem & router. All I have is a tablet and a Samsung Galaxy phone that both use Android. I have tried entering 192.168.1.1 in browser, to no avail.

Seems like you have a Wifi router, not a simple modem. Note that not all Wifi routers use 192.168.1.1 as IP address. And you first have to join the Wifi to be able to communicate to the router.
